# How to add values under the diagonal of a dataframe array into a larger one based on row/column names?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I want to build a correlation matrix of all authors of a series of articles.

First I will build a correlation matrix of all authors to all authors initialized to zeros and represent them with a pandas dataframe.

I will then get the author list of the first article and build a smaller dataframe initilized to ones.

I would finally need to sum the ones under the diagonal of the latter smaller dataframe onto the large one.

After I will repeat this for all articles the end result will be how many times each author has published along with every coauthor.

I would love to avoid explicit iterations and leverage pandas and numpy operations as much as possible.

Here is working code leading to my question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
all_authors = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

#create a numpy array initialized to all zeros with a side length of all_authors
authors_num = len(all_authors)
corr_matrix = np.zeros((authors_num,authors_num),dtype=np.int8)
# create a pandas dataframe using the corr_matrix and add the authors names as indexes and column names
corr_df = pd.DataFrame(data=corr_matrix,    # data
                   index=all_authors,       # row names
                   columns=all_authors)     # column names

article_1_authors = ["a","b","d"]
#create a numpy array initialized to all ones with a side length of the article authors
authors_num = len(article_1_authors)
corr_matrix = np.ones((authors_num,authors_num),dtype=np.int8)
# create a pandas dataframe using the corr_matrix and add the authors names as indexes and column names
auth_df = pd.DataFrame(data=corr_matrix,        # data
                   index=article_1_authors,     # row names
                   columns=article_1_authors)   # column names
```

So from the above dataframe I'd only need to use the a-b a-d and b-d values and sum them into corr_df

How can I do using pandas/numpy operators avoiding for loops and other iterations if possible ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good way of solving the above problem using itertools.combinations. Here is a sample code:

```
for coauthors in author_lists:
    # build all pairwise combinations of article's authors with no repetitions
    new_coauthorship = list(itertools.combinations(coauthors, 2))
    # increment cells in the corr_df for each coauthor pair in the article
   for cell in new_coauthorship:
       corr_df.loc[cell[0],cell[1]] += 1
```